# redefinition error in system header file because of "signed char" and "char"

Tags: c++, linux

I try to include this file

```
 boost/assign/list_of.hpp
```

but i have this compiler's error

```
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/is_integral.hpp:38: error: redefinition of struct boost::is_integral<char>
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/is_integral.hpp:32: error: previous  definition of  struct boost::is_integral<char>
```

these definitions lines (32,38) in file is_integral.hpp are:

```
BOOST_TT_AUX_BOOL_TRAIT_CV_SPEC1(is_integral,signed char,true)
BOOST_TT_AUX_BOOL_TRAIT_CV_SPEC1(is_integral,char,true)
```

how to solve compile problem? the compiler is  gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 OS is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)

Comment: Why must we ask for a MCVE every time?

Comment: IOW, we'll need you to show us the definition of macro `BOOST_TT_AUX_BOOL_TRAIT_CV_SPEC1` *in the question* as well. Thanks.

Comment: We don't, @lightness, you can simply flag the question as off-topic.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: There is little distinction between closing as "requires a MCVE" and asking for an MCVE. I am querying why question authors seemingly cannot follow instructions the first time.

Comment: @JeffY: No, we'll need a _complete_ minimal example of the OP's own test code, as well as version numbers for everything. Posting Boost source code in the question is not appropriate.

Comment: @JeffY : there are recursive complexity for definition of this macro : #ifndef BOOST_NO_CV_SPECIALIZATIONS
#   define BOOST_TT_AUX_BOOL_TRAIT_CV_SPEC1(trait,sp,value) \
    BOOST_TT_AUX_BOOL_TRAIT_SPEC1(trait,sp,value) \
    BOOST_TT_AUX_BOOL_TRAIT_SPEC1(trait,sp const,value) \
    BOOST_TT_AUX_BOOL_TRAIT_SPEC1(trait,sp volatile,value) \
    BOOST_TT_AUX_BOOL_TRAIT_SPEC1(trait,sp const volatile,value) \
    /**/
#else
#   define BOOST_TT_AUX_BOOL_TRAIT_CV_SPEC1(trait,sp,value) \
    BOOST_TT_AUX_BOOL_TRAIT_SPEC1(trait,sp,value) \
    /**/
#endif

Comment: `BOOST_TT_AUX_BOOL_TRAIT_CV_SPEC1(trait, type, val)` simply defines a `trait<type> { static const bool value = val; };`, so the quoted lines specialize a `is_integral<signed char>` and a `is_integral<char>`.

Comment: @YSC: but this file is system file (/usr/include/boost/...) in the server and i don't have permission to change it,

Comment: @dt128 I'm just giving context (you can edit your question to include those additional informations), I can't explain why your compiler complains.

Comment: @YSC So I guess the question is, where in the code is the line `#define signed` and who put it there.

Comment: @JeffY Well, if it's there and compiles for a lot of people, the question is, what in OP's environment make it fail?

Comment: If that's the reason, it doesn't compile for a lot of people, it (or something like it) is rather something local/specific to our OP.

Comment: @dt128 Please try to compile the code snippet I've given in my answer.

Comment: It sounds like you're using incompatible versions of boost and compiler

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it sounds like the MCVE is `#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>`

Comment: @M.M: Perhaps but that needs demonstrating/proving.

Comment: @YSC : i compile & run that: int:, 0!
char:, 1!
unsigned char:, 3!
signed char:, 2!

Answer (score 2):

From C++ standard

> 3.9.1 Fundamental types [basic.fundamental]
>
> Objects declared as characters (char) shall be large enough to store any member of the implementation's basic character set. If a character from this set is stored in a character object, the integral value of that character object is equal to the value of the single character literal form of that character. It is implementation-defined whether a char object can hold negative values. Characters can be explicitly declared unsigned or signed. **Plain char, signed char, and unsigned char are three distinct types**. A char, a signed char, and an unsigned char occupy the same amount of storage and have the same alignment requirements (basic.types); that is, they have the same object representation. For character types, all bits of the object representation participate in the value representation. For unsigned character types, all possible bit patterns of the value representation represent numbers. These requirements do not hold for other types. In any particular implementation, a plain char object can take on either the same values as a signed char or an unsigned char; which one is implementation-defined.

`char`, `unsigned char` and `signed char` are thus three distinct types and `boost::is_integral` should be specializable for those three types. One can expect gcc 4.4.7 or OP's environment to ignore that and I'll be looking for an explanation. Please see this temporary answer as an extended comment on OP's question.

---

**EDIT**: Cannot reproduce

*System*: Red Hat 6

```
$ uname -a
Linux ysc 2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jan 28 21:11:36 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux$
```

*Compiler*:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)
```

*Source*:

```
$ cat main.cpp

#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct trait
{
    static const int value = 0;
};

template<>
struct trait<char>
{
    static const int value = 1;
};

template<>
struct trait<signed char>
{
    static const int value = 2;
};

template<>
struct trait<unsigned char>
{
    static const int value = 3;
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << "int:, " << trait<int>::value << "!\n";
  std::cout << "char:, " << trait<char>::value << "!\n";
  std::cout << "unsigned char:, " << trait<unsigned char>::value << "!\n";
  std::cout << "signed char:, " << trait<signed char>::value << "!\n"; 
}
```

*Compilation*:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra main.cpp
```

*Run*:

```
$ ./a.out 
int:, 0!
char:, 1!
unsigned char:, 3!
signed char:, 2!
```

What does it produce on OP's environment?

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: Comments are limited to 600 characters. What do you suggest?

Comment: I suggest that this entire discussion be had in a chat room instead.